# Total noob at mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, shared-hosting

I am trying to rewrite my URL and having serious issues. I am on a Godaddy linux hosting server and it didn't come with any type of config file or .htaccess file.  I created my own .htaccess file with the below rewrite info but I have no idea how to do anything else:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^NSN/([^/]*)\.html$ /nsn.php?NSN=$1 [L]
```

The people at Godaddy told me I could use URL Redirect to help with this but I am not even sure what that means.

If someone could please help with the next steps of how to make this work, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting URLs is mapping the URL you see in the browser from the default to something more meaningful or memorable. The simplest example is something like this:

```
# Replace all html references with php
RewriteRule html php
```

A [testing tool](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) will save time, and understanding how to use [aliases or redirects](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html) to avoid regular expressions may be helpful.